# Module 'MyApp' is not available

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using angular in my mvc project.

I have added the following js file and called it MyApp.js

```
 (function () {
//Create a Module 
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);  // Will use ['ng-Route'] when we will implement routing

 })();
```

On my _Layout.cshtml I have added ng-app to the body tag

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
        .....
        Code
        .....
</body>
```

On the view I want to display the angular object I have added:

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")

  <script src="../../Scripts/MyApp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/AngularController/BudgetAndDetails.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $('body').on('click', '.CX span', function () {
          //When Click On + sign
          if ($(this).text() == '+') {
              $(this).text('-');
          }
          else {
              $(this).text('+');
          }
          $(this).closest('tr') // row of + sign
            .next('tr') // next row of + sign
            .toggle(); // if show then hide else show

      });
    });
  </script>
 <div ng-controller="BudgetAndDetails">
  <table class="tableData" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <thead>
         <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th>Budget Name</th>
           <th>Year</th>
           <th>Month</th>

       </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="O in budgetdetails">
        <tr ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
            <td class="CX"><span>+</span></td>
            <td>{{O.budget.BudgetName}}</td>
            <td>{{O.budget.Year}}</td>
            <td>{{O.budget.monthname.MonthName1}}</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="sub">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="5">
                <table class="tableData" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Subcateogry</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="a in O.budgetdetails" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                        <td>{{a.category.CategoryName}}</td>
                        <td>{{a.subcategory.SubCategoryName}}</td>
                        <td>{{a.Amount}</td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

In my bundles I added the following code:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                     "~/Scripts/angular-route.js"));
```

However every time i run the program I get the error

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=MyApp

I know I an not misspelling it I read it could be an issue with the order of my scripts. I have tried several alternatives but can't find the problem.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include `MyApp.js` in your view, not in `my_Layout.cshtml`.
Try to include it at the same level as your `<body>`. Angular try to load you app before it is included, which leads to the error. Of course, the part `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")` should be in the `my_Layout.cshtml` too.

I remember that you can have this error if you include twice the same module, make sure you are not inculding twice your `MyApp` module.

Comment: I made your changes but I still got the error. I deleted the MyApp.js file and created it again and now that error is gone. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue and in my case it was just something **in controller**.

I have found that there is a encoding problem with my JSON. If you face the same issue try to empty your controllers and and see if there is a **syntax or encoding error**.